# MySQL 5.7 fails on 'Group By'

Tags: php, mysql

I have read various posts about how Group By has changed since 5.7, however, having attempted the various suggested fixes to my query I continue to get the same error:

```
SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'mysite.customers.company_name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause;
```

Here is my query:

```
 return DB::table('quotations')
        ->join('customers', 'customers.id', '=', 'quotations.customer_id')
        ->select('quotations.reference','company_name','customers.lastname1', 'customers.address', 'quotations.*')
        ->where('quotations.status', '=', 'open')
        ->groupBy('quotations.reference')//   THIS CREATES AN ERROR !
        ->orderBy('created_at')
        ->get();
```

If a company buys 20 things the quote will carry 1 single unique reference  plus the company name,lastname etc. However, each row will have the same reference but **not** the item he bought.

So, when I group by, I am only grouping by the reference, not the product.

So in frustration, I tried the various suggestions for disabling this strict mode, but that did not work either.

**Question:** What do I do to get my query to work ? Thanks !

Comment: A quick search using the error message would be quicker than typing a question

Comment: I have tried every solution on this board - no this is not a duplicate.

Comment: LARAVEL USERS !! ( Like me ! )   Go to app/config/database.php and turn off mysql strict.